# c socket connect error close socket

Tags: c, sockets

this is code

```
    tcp_sockfd = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (tcp_sockfd == -1) {
        printf("Could not create socket");
        return 1;                                                                                                                                           
    }

    if (connect(tcp_sockfd , (struct sockaddr *)&config->tcp_srvaddr , sizeof(config->tcp_srvaddr)) < 0) {
        printf("connect failed. return 1\n");
        return 1;
    }

    struct timeval tv = {30, 0};
    setsockopt(tcp_sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (struct timeval *)&tv, sizeof(struct timeval));

    if(send(tcp_sockfd , data , len , 0) < 0) {
        printf("send failed.\n");    
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Send complete\n");

    close(tcp_sockfd);
```

if socket send or connect fail, have I close socket?
or if error clocket auto close?

Comment: Don't just print your own error messages. Print the actual error: `errno` or better still `strerror(errno)`, or use `perror()`. Otherwise debugging is just a guessing game.

Comment: when outputting error messages, like: `printf("Could not create socket");`  output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.   Suggest using: `perror( "socket failed" );`

Comment: The posted code needs to 'cleanup' after it self, that means, before exiting, close any sockets.

Comment: the call to: `setsockopt()` can fail, the code should be checking for any such failure.

Comment: regarding: `if(send(tcp_sockfd , data , len , 0) < 0) {`  the send function can be successful, but not actually send all the data.  So should be assigning a variable from the returned value and check it for both <0 (followed by a call to `perror()`)  and if <len then (in a loop) call `send() again, with a sliding window, until the whole message is sent

Answer (score 5):

A socket never closes by itself. When you are done with the socket, you need to call `close` to release the descriptor.

Note that the socket remains open as a handle to the connection whether or not the connection itself is open. Closing the connection (for example, with `shutdown` or if initiated by the other side) does not close the socket.